# python subprocess communicate with c++ program

Tags: python, c++, subprocess, ipc

Is it possible to communicate with a C++ program that uses `read() from unistd.h` using python subprocess? when the C++ program is run, data entered gets stored in the file. when i call it from python and try to write data it doesn't seem to capture it.

#### python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import pdb
import subprocess
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(['./std.bin'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)

time.sleep(1)
for  cnt in range(100):
    proc.stdin.write(b'test1\ntest2\n')
    proc.stdin.flush()

proc.stdin.write(b"qq")
```

#### C++ program

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

std::ofstream file_out;
volatile bool ctrlc_pressed = false;

static std::string readline(int fd)
{
  struct termios tios;
  bool noncanonical = tcgetattr(fd, &tios) == 0 && (tios.c_lflag & ICANON) == 0;

  std::string s;
  for (char ch; read(fd, &ch, 1) == 1; )
  {
    if (ch == '\x7f')
    {
      if (s.empty())
        continue;
      s.erase(s.end()-1);

      if (noncanonical && write(fd, "\b \b", 3) != 3)
        ; // shut up gcc
    }
    else if (noncanonical && write(fd, &ch, 1) != 1)
      ; // shut up gcc

    if (ch == '\n')
      break;
    if (ch != '\x7f')
      s += ch;
  }
  return s;
}

int main()
{
    file_out.open("out.txt");
    file_out<<"Started\n"<<std::flush;

  while (1)
  {
    std::cerr << ": " << std::flush;
    std::string s = readline(2);
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string cmd, tmp;

    if (!(ss >> cmd))
    {
      continue;
    }
    if(cmd.find('q')!=std::string::npos) return 0;

    std::cout<<cmd;
    file_out<<cmd<<std::flush;
    while (ss >> tmp)
      {
        std::cout<<' '<<tmp;
        file_out<<' '<<tmp<<std::flush;
    }

    file_out<<'\n'<<std::flush;  

    std::cout<<'\n'<<std::flush;

  }
return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you are trying to read from console output, try using `check_output` instead of `Popen`. Doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: `std::string s = readline(2);` correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't 2 stderr? Wouldn't you want to be reading from stdin?

Comment: @user2085282 maybe you are right. But I'm not the author of the c++ program.

Comment: Has this c++ program successfully been used before? If not, I would suggest contacting the author if possible, or perhaps making the change yourself and seeing if it makes any difference. Unless I'm really having an off moment, that line will never read anything.